# Text layout engine API for C++

Tags: c++, graphics, layout, ghostscript

I have a project where I need to take input text and render it to an image. The text needs to be wrapped, have margins, kerning, letter spacing, specific fonts, and so on. It seems like I could write most of this by hand, but it also seems like something that there should be pre-existing libraries for.

I've looked at web rendering engines like WebKit and Gecko that seem too complex, LaTeX doesn't seem to have a C++ API, GhostScript looks the most promising so far.

I'm writing the app in C++, and I don't want to have to shell-out to a system call--it seems like that will be inflexible and non-performant. It needs to run on Linux, and preferably Mac OSX too.

Thanks for any advice you can offer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subprocesses can be pretty awesome, but I guess you are looking for something like [pango](http://www.pango.org/) or the font rendering engine in Qt. It looks like you can achieve everything you need with [QPainter::drawText(...)](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qpainter.html#drawText-10). See also [QFont](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qfont.html).

It is worth noting that I have dragged in Qt specifically for font rendering before, without using it for anything else. It needs you to create a [QCoreApplication](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qcoreapplication.html)-object, but that's it. Works like a charm :)

Comment: both Pango and QPainter look like exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something lower level (and with fewer dependencies than Qt or Pango) you can use [FreeType](http://www.freetype.org/) directly.  It will take more lines of code to draw the same text (here's their first [example1.c](http://freetype.sourceforge.net/freetype2/docs/tutorial/example1.c)) but it might be less than the lines of `Makefile` required to bring in Qt!